# Split videos after concatenation using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I concatenated multiple videos using the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.avi video2.avi -f concat -c copy -safe 0 -o concat.mov
```

Are there any chance that original files could be splitted back from concat.mov? Since this is a concat and copy, are there any markers in concat.mov that I could utilize?

Update: original video codecs:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'DVR___2017-08-10_09.17.56.AVI':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : DVR ZIR32  SW: 1.1.001
  Duration: 00:20:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 897 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 703 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 5 tbn, 5 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 12000 Hz, mono, s16, 192 kb/s
```

Concatenated file:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'DVR___2017-08-07_19.55.36.AVI.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:52:58.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 875 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 682 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 10240 tbn, 10240 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 12000 Hz, mono, s16, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
```

Comment: Which video codecs ?

Comment: @Mulvya: I updated the questions with codecs.